# I'm having a row with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be a very simple question, and I apologize for it perhaps being too trivial, but somehow I can't see, why for a matrix $M$ with $M\boldsymbol{1}=\boldsymbol{1}$, i.e. the column vector of ones is an eigenvector, this matrix should have some row vector $v$ such that $vM=v$?

Comment: I find your question to be a bit unclear.  For example, did you mean to say ...."but somehow I **can't** see, why for a matrix M..."

Comment: Don't worry about what anyone thinks in terms of "triviality" etc. That shouldn't matter at all, anyway. I'm just trying to understand you more clearly, that's all.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, sorry, that's waht

Comment: @amWhy Yes, sorry, "can't" is what I meant of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $\det(M-I)=0$. Transposing, we have  $$0=\det((M-I)^T)=\det(M^T-I)$$ 
and thus $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M^T$, hence there is some column vector $u$ such that $u=M^Tu$.  Now writing $v=u^T$ we have
$$v=u^T=(M^Tu)^T=u^T(M^T)^T=vM$$

Comment: Is the part of the explanation with the determinant needed ? I feel that the proof with $v=u^T$ is self-sufficient.

Comment: If you know how the eigenvalues of $M$ and $M^T$ are related, then no it's not necessary.